# How to access to entity field by attribute name in core data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I have entity with attribute id.
I seen example:

```
var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
      var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "myentity")
      request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
      if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) {
      if results.count > 0 {
                for result: AnyObject in results {
                    println(result.id)
                }    
      }
```

But for me it return error:'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'id'
How can I do it in last version Xcode in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an NSManagedObject Subclass. Once you have done this you can access the attributes using dot syntax rather than using object for key. Apple's documentation on NSManagedObject can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html) and information about creating the subclass [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_mo_class.html). Then in your for loop you cast the object as your managed object subclass type.

```
var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
if !fetchedResultController.performFetch(error)
{
    println("Unresolved error: \(error), \(error.debugDescription)")
}

let results = fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects as [YourSubclass]

for result in results {
    println(result.id)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand from where fetchedResultController?

Comment: That's referring to NSFetchResultsController, but you can just use `context.executeFetchRequest(request, nil)` instead